# Javascript setter override value before setting

Tags: javascript

What I essentially want to do is this:

```
Blog.prototype = {
  set content(content) {
    this.content = JSON.parse(content);
  }
}
```

However, this results in infinite recursion.

I know I can do something like:

```
  set content(content) {
    this._content = JSON.parse(content);
  },

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
```

However, when I do `JSON.stringify(blog)`, it doesn't include `content`, but includes `_content`, which is undesirable.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: You may define `toJSON` an serialise manually.

Answer (score 5):

Make the "_content" variable non-enumerable.

```
Blog.prototype = {
  set content(newContent) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, "_content", { 
      value: JSON.parse(newContent), 
      writable: true 
    });
  },
  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
};
```

By default, an the "enumerable" flag for an object property is `false` if not supplied explicitly in the call to `defineProperty()`.

Someday the Symbol type will be universally supported, and it'd be a better choice for this because you can make a guaranteed unique property key that way. If you don't need IE support and can use Symbols:

```
Blog.prototype = () => {
  const internalContent = Symbol("content key");
  return {
    set content(newContent) {
      this[internalContent] = newContent;
    },
    get content() {
      return this[internalContent];
    }
  };
}();
```

Symbol-keyed properties are ignored by `JSON.stringify()` so you don't have to bother with `defineProperty()`. The nice thing about the Symbol approach is that you don't have to worry about collisions. Every Symbol instance returned from `Symbol()` is distinct.

Comment: @zerkms sorry I meant something like "universally supported".

Comment: This worked. Can you explain why your answer worked but @apendua's didn't?

Comment: @AndyBroda because they create a property with a different name?

Comment: @AndyBroda well the other answer had the same problem as the original: property name collision. There's only one namespace for string-named properties.

Comment: @AndyBroda My version is in fact incorrect, because you wont be able to set the value again. I was a little bit too quick, sorry.

Comment: @Pointy hmm, this doesn't seem to include `content` by default with `JSON.Stringify()`. How can I make `content` appear as a normal property? I don't want to override `toJson` since I would also want it to appear as a normal property to lodash or underscore, i.e `_.merge(blog1, blog2)`, I would want it to be copied over.

Comment: Actually not sure this solves my issue. I think it was a coincidence that it worked on some attempt, but the issue still remains that this doesn't actually set the value of `content`.

Comment: Figured out a solution based off your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41091842/458960

Comment: @AndyBroda you need a getter too; I left that out of the answer but I'll add it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Set and Get with `_content`, and implement [`.toJson()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior) to provide `JSON.stringify` with `content` instead of `_content`.

```
toJSON() {
  return {
    content: this._content
  }
}
```

---

According to MDN `.toJSON()` role is:

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value
>   is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON
>   stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the
>   value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized.

---

**Using with a constructor function**

```js
function Blog() {}

Blog.prototype = {
  set content(content) {
    this._content = JSON.parse(content);
  },

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  },
  
  toJSON() {
    return {
      content: this._content
    }
  }
};

var blog = new Blog();

blog.content = '{ "a": "5" }';

console.log(blog.content);

console.log(JSON.stringify(blog));
```

**Using with ES6 class**

```js
class Blog {
  set content(content) {
    this._content = JSON.parse(content);
  }

  get content() {
    return this._content;
  }
  
  toJSON() {
    return {
      content: this._content
    }
  }
};

const blog = new Blog();

blog.content = '{ "a": "5" }';

console.log(blog.content);

console.log(JSON.stringify(blog));
```

Comment: `blog.content = '{ "a": "5" }';` since `JSON.parse` accepts a string.

Comment: Now - your setter does not even run. Make `Blog` a function and create an instance using a `new` operator.

Comment: Thanks again. I've converted it into a constructor function.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by building off Pointy's answer:

```
var Blog = function () {
  var content;

  Object.defineProperty(this, "content", {
    get: function() {
      return content;
    },
    set: function(value) {
      content = JSON.parse(value);
    },
    enumerable: true,
  });
};
```

The trick here is the `enumerable` flag, which is false by default.